# Sign of eigenvalues of a real $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I want to find just the sign of $3$ eigenvalues of a given real symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ without actually calculating the eigenvalues. Is there any way I can do it based on only the matrix entries and the given information?

Comment: You can use the determinant to see whether there is an even number of negative eigenvalues (assuming none of them are $0$). That's halfway there.

Comment: That is true, but I have no guarantee that none of the eigenvalues will be zero. I was wondering if sign of principal minors will convey any information

Comment: Given the matrix is symmetric, you can only say all the Eigen Values are real. Additional information, for example positive definiteness say that the Eigen Values are positive.

Comment: No additional information is available.

Comment: Then one check is if the Determinant is negative, you can say either 1 or all 3 Eigen Values are negative. If Determinant is positive, nothing can be concluded.

Comment: Can we atleast say something about sign of the largest eigenvalue in absolute sense

Comment: *Every principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix is positive definite.* see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix#Submatrices

Comment: It will help us identify the case when all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: In certain cases we can indeed deduce the sign of the eigenvalues from the principal minors, but there are exceptional cases where the principal minors do not yield enough information.

Comment: What are those cases

Comment: You can use Routh-Hurwitz criterion applied to characteristic polynomial of A.

Answer (score 1):

About the example of user1551, we see that it has two positive and one negative eigenvalue. Sylvester says that the eigenvalues must match up with the diagonal elements of $D;$
   these may vary depending on choices made while solving $P^THP = D.$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

====================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may use Sylvester's law of inertia.

In general, you can diagonalise a real symmetric matrix $A$ *by congruence* (whose computational complexity is in general lower than orthogonal diagonalisation). Then the signs of the resulting diagonal matrix are the signs of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Alternatively, if your matrix happens to contain a nested sequence of *nonzero* principal minors, you can apply the (lesser known) sign-change version of Sylvester's law of inertia without performing any diagonalisation. More specifically, suppose that there exists a (reversely) nested sequence of principal submatrices $A_0,A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ of $A$ such that each $A_k$ is nonsingular and $k\times k$ (here $A_0$ by convention denotes the empty matrix with determinant $1$ and $A_n=A$) and $A_{k-1}$ is contained in $A_k$. Then the number of sign changes in the numeric sequence
$$
\det(A_0)\,(=1),\,\det(A_1),\ldots,\det(A_{n-1}),\,\det(A_n)\,(=\det(A))
$$
is the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$. E.g. consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&1&2\\ 1&2&-3}.
$$
Then $1,\,\det(A(2,2))=1,\,\det(A(2:3,\,2:3))=-7,\,\det(A)=-1$ is a sequence of nonzero nested principal minors. Since there is only one sign change (between $\det(A_1)$ and $\det(A_2)$) in the sequence, we conclude that $A$ has one negative eigenvalue and two positive eigenvalues.

Note that the choice of the nested principal minors does not matter as long as these minors are nonzero. To illustrate, the $A$ in the example above has only three sequences of nonzero nested principal minors:

- $1,\,\det(A(2,2))=1,\,\det(A(2:3,\,2:3))=-7,\,\det(A)=-1$,
- $1,\,\det(A(3,3))=-3,\,\det(A(2:3,\,2:3))=-7,\,\det(A)=-1$,
- $1,\,\det(A(3,3))=-3,\,\det(A(\{1,3\},\,\{1,3\}))=-1,\,\det(A)=-1$.

We see that in every one of them, the number of sign changes remains the same (namely, exactly $1$).